What is an external interruption? MicroPython pyb.stop() function help
when it comes to MicroPython pyb.stop() function, I know it's used to make the chip interact only if a external interruption comes around, but I'm starting to wonder what the external interruption is supposed to be, is it like an electrical signal being sent to the chip, or is it something else?

An external interrupt is a signal or pulse coming from outside the microcontroller, like a change in voltage on one of the microcontroller’s GPIO (General Purpose Input/Output) pins. When the microcontroller is in standby mode, it watches for specific changes on certain pins that are designated as "interrupt pins." When an event on one of these pins is detected, it "wakes up" the microcontroller and resumes operations. Some examples of an interrupt event can be a button press, a switch, a sensor capturing something, or some other external event that basically tells the microcontroller that something changed.

thank you so much :)

Traditionally, external interrupt refers to the MCU having a pin explicitly for this purpose, often called IRQ and often "non-maskable" meaning you wouldn't be able to disable it. All Motorola-flavoured MCUs had such a design.
To separate IRQ from GPIO interrupts, the latter are sometimes called "keyboard wakeup". What you describe sounds like a sleep mode for energy saving purposes. That could either be using a dedicated pin or GPIO, depending on MCU.
You will probably not get any wiser from reading Python documentation about this. Instead study the manual of the specific MCU used in the project.

The pin may also be labelled in the datasheet as NMI for "non-maskable interrupt".
